# Count all non-zeroes for series of columns in a df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to create a new column that will have a count function. This count function should count the non-zero values in specified columns of the df, while ignoring the other columns.

I've tried counting non-zero values, but it's including a column that I want it to ignore. I only want it to count columns 2-9 (assuming first column is 0) with non-zero values.

```
maps_scVelo['Pitch Count'] = (maps_scVelo.count(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

Pitcher ID  Pitcher Fastball    Sinker  Cutter  Slider  Changeup    Curve   Splitter    Knuckle Count

434378   Justin Verlander   95.1    0   91.5    86.7    87.4    79.7    0   0   5
```

Answer (score 0):

.count counts the non-NaN values. You can use != 0 and .sum to count the non-zero:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [0, 'c']], columns=['A', 'B'])

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   A  B
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  0  c
```

Get the boolean DataFrame of those non-zero:

```
In [13]: df != 0
Out[13]:
       A     B
0  False  True
1   True  True
2  False  True
```

and take the column sum:

```
In [14]: (df != 0).sum()
Out[14]:
A    1
B    3
dtype: int64
```

To select only the numeric columns you can use select_dtypes (with np.number):

```
In [15]: df.select_dtypes(np.number)
Out[15]:
   A
0  0
1  1
2  0

In [16]: (df.select_dtypes(np.number) != 0).sum()
Out[16]:
A    1
dtype: int64
```